# Sum Value based on calculated measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have dataset as below. Name of Dataset is table:
[Image of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUuTl.png)

Then I have a visualization table which can be summarised as below. Note the Final Category change if period 1 is selected of if the range period 1-2 is selected based on the sum of each fruits:

[Period 1 Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRRw6.png)
[Period 1-2 Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm95i.png)

Final Category is a measure:

```
Final Category = IF (
        SUM('Table'[Amount])>0,
        SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Category > 0],0),
        SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Category < 0]],0)
)
```

Note the value are interactive. I have a slicer which change a period and based on the period the value stored as amount is going to change.

If I select period 1-2 I would like to see the final output below :

![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJNti.png)

Do you have any idea how I can achieve that?

I have tried to create a separate visual table using the measure 'Final Category' as one of the Columns and then try to calculate the Eur Amount. The problem is that this new table is returning 0 as 'Final Category' unless I select a value from my initial table.

Answer (score 0):

First create a calculated column `Final Category`

[image]

Then create a table using summarize dax function

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ashle for your feedback but it's not the solution I'm looking for. The first table in y example is a visualization (I-e its already the result from a range of data shown as a visualisation)

Comment: I'm going to update my request to clarify this point